# Transition from coordinate space to momentum space for SHO

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wavefunction, fourier-transform

I am given that the ground state of the SHO in position space is given as
$$\langle q|\psi_0\rangle=\frac{1}{a^{\frac12}\pi^{\frac14}}e^{-q/4a^2}$$
Where a is a constant with units of length.  I am then asked to find the corresponding momentum space distribution.  I know this will be related to a fourier transform, but I am unsure how to put it in this notation.  I also know:
$$\langle q|p \rangle=ce^{ipq/\hbar}.$$
Now to get from $\langle q|\psi_0 \rangle$ to $\langle p|\psi_0\rangle$ I am unsure of which properties to use.

Comment: Hint: Use the fact that $|\alpha\rangle=\sum_{a'}|a'\rangle\langle a'|\alpha\rangle$ with $\sum_{a'}|a'\rangle\langle a'|=1$.

Comment: Is this the same as doing $\langle p|\psi_0\rangle=\langle p|q \rangle\langle q|\psi_0 \rangle$ ?

Comment: Yes it is, I just used the generalized form for an arbitrary ket.

Comment: Not quite, you still need to integrate...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As very often in these sorts of proof, we just need to use a completeness relation: We have,
\begin{align}
\langle p | \psi _0 \rangle & = \langle p  | \int dq |q \rangle  \langle q | \psi _0 \rangle \\ 
& = \int dq e ^{ - i p q } \langle q | \psi _0 \rangle   \\ 
& =  \frac{1}{ \sqrt{ a \sqrt{ \pi }}} \int dq  e ^{ - i p q } e ^{ - q^2 / 4 a ^2 } \\
& =  \frac{1}{ \sqrt{ a \sqrt{ \pi }}} 2a \sqrt{\pi}e ^{-a^2p^2}\\
&= 2 \sqrt{a \pi} e ^{-p^2/a^2}
\end{align} 
The integral is just a Gaussian. Note that you may get a slightly different result due to normalizations, etc.